# I want to automate rebooting most or all of the major routers remotely, will provide software to everyone for free

Tags: windows, router, reboot, remote, telnet

Does anyone know if we can use a tool or a method to remotely restart the router? Or even remotely restart the internet connection of the router?

I know we can telnet into the router, but each router has different menu systems and sub menu systems, does anyone know a list that maintains or shows the menu system to reach the "reboot router" sub menu or "restart internet connection" sub menu for all or even some of the main routers? I'm mainly interested in home/personal use routers.

If this link exists, i can write the software to automate the rebooting of the router and even the rebooting of the internet connection.

Of course, once i write the software, i will make it freely available over the internet for everyone to use, and i will also link to it from this superuser.com post so that anyone reading this post will know how to download and use my software.

I can automate everything. Even if you want to shutdown your router before shutting down your computer, i can create a button that will shut down your router and (once it is confirmed as shut down) my program will then shut down your pc/laptop/computer.

Of course, the rebooting part will be the section that is mostly used, and that will also be a one button click process.

If anyone can direct me to how to navigate through the submenus for most routers in order to reach the rebooting router or rebooting internet connection section, i will make different buttons for each process and this will solve the problem for everyone.

It would be my absolute pleasure to do this for you all and for everyone to use, I don't care how long it takes me to write it, even if it takes ages, I will do it.

Any advice anyone?

Also, I don't consider logging into the http interface and trying to reboot from there, since that takes too many mouse movements and button clicks. I intend to make all the features a one button click process.

I would totally appreciate anyone who can lead me in the right direction to achieve this. Thanks all.

Comment: I just use a radio transmitter linked to the power switch on my own router, saves me walking down 3 floors... & feels somehow... safer ;-)

Comment: @Tetsujin I really need a remote solution, i know it's possible because there is a windows gadget plugin that does it, but it doesn't work for all routers, asks for password & username which most people don't know, and I know how to make it better if I have the information requested.

Comment: @davidpostill My question is certainly not off topic, where am I supposed to post a question like this if not here? Do you get a kick out of making this website less user friendly? Please don't be another [CasperOne] who is a rampant post closer and closes posts without even reading or understanding the question, mainly because he can't know everything about programming. By doing what you did, you are just removing value from the site, you are not adding value. Being a good person means everyone wins, I am willing to write this software that so many can use for free, why harm the community?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this sounds creepy.  You want to reboot my router?

Why don't you start with rebooting your router remotely, then enhance it to reboot the router of someone who will allow you to do theirs.  I think by the time you do two, you will come to see the futility of the task you have chosen.

Or did I miss something?

Comment: Your response is sort of appropriate to the question, but it's borderline whether it meets the definition of an answer on the site.  A good answer would either explain how to do what was asked or explain why it isn't possible.  For future questions of this ilk, consider doing this type of response as a comment.  Some people are trigger-happy with downvotes and use them to educate new users.

Comment: Why couldn't you understood my question? I want to provide a button so that people can have multiple ways to reboot/shutdown their routers (very useful when network errors occur). Of course, I'll be testing it on my own router before making my software freely available to help people and improve their standard of living. Why? Because I (like many others) don't want to walk to the other side of the house or up/down 3 floors several times a day just to recycle/reboot their routers when they stop working. And @fixer1234 how on earth could both you and AngelaS interpret my intentions as malicious?

Comment: Every single time I post on SO or SU I have to put up with people like this who are either rampant post closers or deliberately misinterpret my clearly worded question as something other than what it is. I'm beginning to think there is something wrong with us programmers & computer admins. Were we tortured at high school for being smarter than the bullies? Are we now taking out our aggression on one another as a psychological response in order to feel better about ourselves? This sort of thing happens far too often for it to be coincidental now, and this behavior is especially rampant on SE.

Comment: @user51047 - The site isn't designed for "big" questions.  A good answer to your question would be outside the scope of the site.  From what you describe, you need too much information in too many areas.  If you are experiencing this a lot, as you indicate, it is probably because you aren't familiar with the nature of the site and the type of questions it is designed to handle.  The few standard "off-topic" messages sometimes don't exactly fit.  Read the help center rules and look at other questions.  It's not personal.  Your questions are the common denominator.

Comment: @user51047 - You want to develop an application, possibly involving both software and hardware.  There are a multitude of technologies that could be used and an endless list of software applications and programming languages.  You want something applicable to a broad range of routers and computer hardware.  It takes expertise in a number of areas to do this and it sounds like you are starting from a point where you lack some basic knowledge.  So to get from here to there is way beyond the scope of what this site can provide, especially in one question.

Comment: @fixer1234 Ok, then in this case, pointing that out would be fine, instead of AngelaS accusing me of malicious intent. Really, I'd be happy to learn, one by one, the menu system for each type of router so that I can interact with them via software (telnet) which I'll write. I already use UPnP but it's terribly limited. I just need a way to automate rebooting or reconnecting commands with any router using telnet, once i can do this, I can figure out how to speak to the rest of the routers. There must be a site which shows the telnet accessible menu system for at least some of the routers.

Comment: @fixer1234 If I can't get access to the menu system for at least some or most of the routers, I'm going to need to buy each type of router one by one in order to learn how to communicate with them via telnet so that I can then automate this telnet communication. I know there are other protocols one can use to talk to routers, but I haven't even had the opportunity to investigate them yet, nor do I know if they could be used to reboot or reconnect the router.